# Writing a variadic Scala predicate method

Tags: scala, variadic

I have following example:

```
val check30 = allTrue(x:Int => x%2 == 0, x:Int => x%3 == 0, x:Int => x%5== 0)
val check30(60) //evaluates to true
```

I want to write a predicate method `allTrue` which takes several predicates, like in the example, and combines them via `foldRight`.

I tried something like this:

```
def allTrue[T](pred: T =>Boolean*): Boolean =
    pred.foldRight(true)(_ && _)
```

However this doesnt work.

How can I do this right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you didn't pass the value you want to test. You can do:

```
def allTrue[T](pred: T => Boolean*)(value: T): Boolean =
  pred.forall(p => p(value))
```

Then to use it:

```
val check30 = allTrue[Int](_ % 2 == 0, _ % 3 == 0, _ % 5 == 0)(_)
val result = check30(60) //evaluates to true
println(result)
```

Using `foldRight` you can do:

```
def allTrue[T](pred: T => Boolean*)(value: T): Boolean =
  pred.foldRight(true)((p, b) => b && p(value))
```

Code run at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/kK4tZMqTRtidEXQJo66rhA).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Very helpful! But I want to do it with foldRight...

Comment: @gython Why would you want to do that with `foldRight`? `forall` stops on first false condition, which improves performance.

Comment: you are absolutely right! However I want to practice the usage of ``foldRight`` and ``foldLeft``.